# multi page password protection

Tags: pages, security, password

Is it possible to have the "password protected page" feature of WordPress apply to more than one page? I have dozens of pages which I wish to protect with the same password, but I don't want people to keep having to type the password every time they open a new page. I also don't want people to require an account, all they should need is one password!

Comment: I guess you could use a combination of cookies and transients. So far not sure if this is really a WP question... Interesting tough. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

WordPress FTW! It actually works this way out of the box. If you use the same password on multiple pages, it only has to be entered once.

Comment: is that a documented feature?

Comment: Great question; I have no idea. A while back I was going to do the same thing and just tested it, figuring "hey, maybe..." and I was pleasantly surprised, so it just so happened to be documented in my head. A cursory Google search reveals nothing. I'm adding it [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/index.php?title=Using_Password_Protection) now, as that seems as good a place as any!